# Invoking clearInterval for a Property Instance of an Initialized Custom jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written many js scripts & jQuery plugins, so here's a condensed pseudo coded scenario of my dilemma.

Assume we have a well written jQuery plugin defining an a method object to pass into our plugin.

```
// OUR HYPOTHETICAL jQUERY PLUGIN
(function($){

var methods = {
    init : function(options){
        var setup = $.extend({
            'speed' : 300,
            'msg' : 'blah'
        }, options)

        return this.each(function(){
            var animation = setInterval(function(){ ... },1000)
            ...
        })

    },
    stop : function(){
        window.clearInterval(animation); // DOES NOT WORK
    }
};

$.fn.somePlugin = function(method){
     // Method calling logic
        if ( methods[method] ) {
          return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
          return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Bad Method...' );
        }   
};

})(jQuery)
```

Let imagine instantiate this plugin to a div `$('#someDiv').somePlugin();`

Everything up to this point works fine and I'm able to call... 
`$('#someDiv').somePlugin('stop');`

However, the inside of the **stop** method is not able to figure out how to access the instance of the animation property that was created during the plugin initialization.

Any ideas on how to get that specific instance of the **animation** variable that's associated to the plugin binded to **#someDiv**.

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because the animation var is local. Use the animation (one array) var as a plugin property, so it will be local to the plugin instance. I think that using this approach you will achieve what you need.

One example:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="btnStart"/>Start</button>
<button id="btnStop"/>Stop</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var obj = {
    size: 5,
    animationsId: [],
    start: function() {
        for ( var i = 0; i < this.size; i++ ) {
            this.animationsId[i] = setInterval( function() {
                console.log( "aaa" );
            }, 500 );
        }
    },
    stop: function() {
        for ( var i = 0; i < this.size; i++ ) {
            clearInterval( this.animationsId[i] );
        }
    }
};

$( "#btnStart" ).click(function(){
    obj.start();
});

$( "#btnStop" ).click(function(){
    obj.stop();
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/3fDHF/

Answer (score 0):

You could store the interval token inside the data for each element. For instance...

```
var animation = setInterval(function(){ ... },1000)
$(this).data('somePlugin', {animationInterval: animation});
```

Then later you can access it for the particular element...

```
window.clearInterval($(this).data('somePlugin').animationInterval);
```